# How do I compare a record in a csv (txt) file to a record in another csv (txt) file and calculate a number based on their comparison?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to compare words in a csv (txt) file to those in another csv (txt) file using Python. I am then trying to calculate a score based on their similarity. One file (Answer.txt) contains answers for a test. The other (Test.txt) contains both the definitions and answers of the test. The problem is that I am fairly new to coding and that both files have a different layout. For example, Answers.txt has a layout like this:

```
dog,cat,sheep
```

Test.txt has a layout like this:

```
definition_1,def_2,def_3
dog,cat,sheep
```

For every row in Answer.txt I am trying to compare each word to the last row in Test.txt. I am also trying to calculate a score based on the matching words. If a word matches, I would like 2 marks to be awarded. For example:

If the answers in Answer.txt say:

```
dog,cat,sheep
```

And the answers in Test.txt say:

```
dog,cat,sheep
```

... A score of 6 will be calculated. However, if the answers in Answers.txt say:

```
dog cat,shep
```

... Then 4 points will be awarded, because 'sheep' does not match Test.csv.

I would then like this 'score' to be added to the end of a record in another file called 'Score.txt'.

Sorry for the trouble. This is just about as simplified as I can make my explanation. You're help will be massively appreciated!

Added:

I have no idea where to start. I have, however, written the function which stores the user's input in Answers.txt:

```
def ask_question(number, definition):
    """ Asks a question for definition number """
    print "Definition {}: {}".format(number, definition)
    return raw_input("Answer: ")

def sit_a_test():
    results = []
    with open("Test.txt", "rb") as f:
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            results.append(list(ask_question(no, def) for no, def in enumerate(row))))

    with open("Score.txt", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writerow.writerows(results)
```

Comment: You have to show what __you__ have tried first.

Comment: Sorry about the layout there.

Comment: Code won't be easily readable in the comments section. Instead, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22744556/edit) your question to add relevant details!

Comment: @TheElderLatham better edit your question and add code there

Comment: I have to go so I can't give you an answer.  However, if you are reading in a csv file you could read each line as a line dictionary and then you can easily manipulate each key value pair - the key is the column heading 'def_1' the value is the answer. then you can manipulate each item very easily see this [page](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse140/13wi/csv-parsing.html) it is where I learned how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, using numpy

```
import numpy as np

# Load the files:
answers = np.loadtxt(open("Answer.txt"), dtype='str', delimiter=",")
test = np.loadtxt(open("Text.txt"), dtype='str', delimiter=",")

# Compare
scores = 2 * np.sum(answers == test, axis=0)

# save
np.savetxt("Score.csv", scores, delimiter=",")
```